# GETUTCDATE() and Time Zone (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to add my time zone with the function GETUTCDATE() in SQL Server. I searched several times, but did not found any relevant solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `GETUTCDATE` use [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx). It will return a `datetimeoffset` value that include the machine's timezone offset. If you want to switch this to another offset, use [SWITCHOFFSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

***only for sql 2016***, it takes into account daylight savings.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetBelgiumTime 
(
)
RETURNS datetime2
AS BEGIN  
       declare @dateoffset datetimeoffset
       SET  @dateoffset = convert(VARCHAR(2000),(SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE  'Central European Standard Time'),126 )


       declare @date datetime2
       set @date = convert(datetime2, LEFT(@dateoffset,28),126)

    set @date = DATEADD(HOUR, convert(int,LEFT(RIGHT(@dateoffset,5), 2)), @date) 
       RETURN @date
END

select  dbo.GetBelgiumTime() as BelgiumDateAndTime
```

Comment: All that conversion to and from varchars and dateadd, is unnecessary. Just use `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` instead of `GETUTCDATE` and the `AT TIME ZONE` will convert correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2016 forward (and Azure SQL DB), you can do this:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE @tz
```

where @tz is a valid Windows time zone identifier, such as `'Pacific Standard Time'`, `'Central European Standard Time'`, etc.

However, if you are on an older version of SQL Server, or prefer to use IANA time zone identifiers, you can use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project to do the following:

```
SELECT Tzdb.UtcToLocal(GETUTCDATE(), @tz)
```

where `@tz` is an IANA standard time zone name, such as `'America/Los_Angeles'` or `'Europe/Budapest'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GETDATE()` instead `GETUTCDATE()`. see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#lower-precision-system-date-and-time-functions)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `switchoffset` like this:

```
select switchoffset(CAST(myDate as datetimeoffset),'+05:30')  from someTable
```

Instead of `'+05:30'` you can specify your timezone value.

If you want to use the timezone with GETUTCDATE() then simply add it like this

```
select cast(GETUTCDATE() as varchar(20)) + '+5:30'
```

and if you want to keep it as date only then

```
select  switchoffset(CAST(GETUTCDATE() as datetimeoffset),'+05:30')
```

Comment: this is not daylight savings time away.Fail