# Azure SQL display local time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to display datetime values in local time. By default, Azure SQL Database stores dates and times in UTC, there is no way around this. (This was a pain when migrating from on premise SQL Server.) I would like to display a stored time value in Central European time.

Now the local time is 11:30 (CET). UTC time is 10:30.

```
DECLARE @TestTime DATETIME;
SET @TestTime = '2016-11-02 10:30:00'

SELECT @TestTime
--Returns 2016-11-02 10:30:00
SELECT @TestTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'
--Returns 02 November 2016 10:30:00 +01:00
```

I need to return 2016-11-02 11:30:00 somehow. Now for the fun part:

As has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953903/how-can-i-convert-a-sql-server-2008-datetimeoffset-to-a-datetime):

```
SELECT convert(DATETIME,@TestTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time',1)
--Returns 2016-11-02 09:30:00 So instead of adding the timezonedifference it subtracts it.
```

This works, but makes me sick:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEPART(tz,@TestTime AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'),@TestTime)
--Returns 2016-11-02 11:30:00
```

A similar solution has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101830/getutcdate-and-time-zone-sql-server), but it plays with string operations. My suspicion is that something is wrong in AT TIME ZONE; it should have displayed 11:30 +1, and not 10:30 +1, no?

Is there really no proper way to display a UTC time in local time? This "hacking around it" feels awfully dirty, especially since at any point in time it just might stop working (e.g. Microsoft fixes / introduces a bug).

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to display the local date time in, in the end?

Comment: @drediske In [CET](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet). All I want to see in the example is 11:30. (Actually my db has users from a few other timezones, and daylight saving comes to play too, so it is a bit more complex.) It boils down to being able to convert the stored UTC time values to the desired local time.

Comment: I love these uncommented -1s... I'd love to improve the question if the voter enlightened me.

Comment: I know you wanted CET- I meant, how are you exposing the data? Your conversion may be better suited (say on a webpage) by using the local system timezone than the CET hardset. UTC (and the cloud) is de-localized, which you want to undo. Why not do it at the last possible moment (say, in your webpage)?

Comment: @drediske Oh, I see now. These timestamps are order times. The do not depend on the user's local settings, but on the country of residence of the company from which they order. This setting comes from the DB - every company has a TimeZone field. You are right on the "as late as possible" thing. I'm only putting together Views and SP-s to be used on the website, I'm not trying to store the localized time.. And seeing that our web devs are bleeding through all pores, I thought I'd take some load off them and serve up ready to use data.

Comment: tl, dr: I'm creating views and SPs that serve the website the required order data, where times must be displayed in a specified time zone.

Comment: So you're looking for use case A, roughly? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx

Comment: @drediske Yes, but that just doesn't work that way as explained in their example. I'm puzzled here. I must be missing something very obvious. By the way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AT TIME ZONE` statement performs *two* distinct operations:

1. To ***assert*** that a `datetime` (or `datetime2`) is in a particular time zone, thus looking up the correct offset for that zone and returning a `datetimeoffset` value with the correct offset applied.
2. To ***convert*** a `datetimeoffset` value to a different time zone, using the offset from the source value to pin down an exact point in time, then looking up the new offset for the requested time zone and applying it.  This returns a `datetimeoffset` with a potentially different local time and offset than the original, but representing the same moment in time.

You are using the first part only.  To convert a `datetime` from UTC to a specific time zone, you'll need to use *both*.

```
SELECT @TestTime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'
```

The first `AT TIME ZONE` asserts that the input `datetime` is in UTC, resulting in a `datetimeoffset` that has `+00:00` for the offset.  The second `AT TIME ZONE` converts that to the time zone requested.

Comment: Also, I notice your profile says you're in Budapest, so it would be more correct to use the `"Central Europe Standard Time"` zone instead.  Though in this case, there's no difference other than the `an` in the ID.  Refer to [this mapping](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

Comment: Wow, thank you! It is a little bit weird, but actually makes sense with your explanation. And another big thanks for the `"Central Europe Standard Time"`, I bow before your knowledge. :)