# TimeZone Implementation For a SaaS

Tags: sql, sql-server, internationalization, timezone, timezone-offset

I am working on a SaaS product where the data has to be loaded to the consumer (End User) based on the producers (Client) time availablity, unfortunately the time availability of the producers are not stored in UTC, So I have tried the following technique to fetch the records,

```
--@offSet = '+05:30'
Select * From ProducerAvailablitiy
Where producerTimeSlot is 
between Cast(switchoffset(GETUTCDATE(),@offSet)  As datetime) and Cast(switchoffset(GETUTCDATE(),@offSet) + 1
```

I have a table with list of timezone offset, which are refrenced to the producer (Client) this seems to be working properly as of now. But I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info). According to it single timezone can have multiple offset (Daylight savings)
so I just want to know how to tackle this situation.

Comment: (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388919/634824) in the dup link)

Comment: will it handle daylight savings offset variance?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Comment: @MattJohnson I have  implemented the following suggestion, it seemed to be working fine till then but now when we are checking for Alaskan Standard Time 'AT TIME ZONE' gives -08:00 where as it should be -09:00 now.

DST: Mar 12, 2017 - Nov, 05 2017

Comment: Today is only October 24th.  DST is still in effect, so -8 is correct.  It will go back to -9 at 2:00 am on November 5th.  See: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/anchorage